# I have designed and coded a website, but when i zoom in on the browser it resizes

Tags: html, css, layout

I have worked very hard on this website but i have ran into an annoyance that I cannot seem to figure out! I am using Mozilla Firefox and unlike other webpages, when I zoom everything moves out of place! Usually that only happens when you resize but for some reason it is doing it for zoom also!! How can I fix this? Here is the code bellow:) Thanks! P.S. My zoom is at 90%, if there is a way to automatically set the zoom of browser when the user opens the page, please let me know!

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(backgrounds/background4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body{
    width:100%;
}
.mainHeader{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    /*background-color:#182418;*/
    /*opacity:0.7;*/
}
.mainHeader nav ul{
    margin-right:70px;
    float:right;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#ACACAC;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a.active{
    color:white;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
}
.mainHeader img{
    margin-top:-25px;
}
.mainArea .panel{
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-top:2%;
    width:50%;
  height:620px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.mainArea .panel h1{
  color:white;
  font-family:Arial;
  padding:50px;
  padding-left:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.mainArea .panel p{
  color:white;
  font-family:Arial;
  padding:30px 50px 50px 50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
}
.mainArea .panel form{
  margin-right:33%;
    position:relative;
    top:-5%;
    float:right;
}
.mainArea .panel form .name, .email{
  width:300px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    border:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:gray;
}
.mainArea .panel form .body{
  resize:none;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    border:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:gray;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.mainArea .panel form .submit{
    width:90px;
    height:43px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    border:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:gray;
    padding-top:-3px;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
.mainArea .panel form .submit:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jqueryui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mainHeader">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="mainArea">
        <div class="panel">
          <h1>Welcome to our contact page!</h1>
          <form action="php/mail.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" value="Name" name="name" class="name"><br/>
            <input type="text" value="Email" name="email" class="email"><br/>
            <textarea name="message" class="body" rows="4" cols="50">What would you like to ask?</textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send!" class="submit">
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the background named background4.jpg Also, if you try to run the code snipet on this site it will get messed up because of the way stack overflow is laid out and because it needs the background image. So copying to a text file would work best.
[image: background4.jpg]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand but check this out http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/

Comment: If the code snippet feature on SO does not work properly to demonstrate your issue, then please don't use it.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your elements get dispersed while zooming or re-sizing your browser window
use `min-width` and `min-height` for the containers
that will make them stay in the right way you like them
try to add this line :

```
.mainArea .panel {
min-width: 790px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't an universal way for browsers to zoom everything. At least not without a whole lot of scripting.

In my opinion it's also pretty weird to design a website and force browsers to 90%.

Zooming isn't what people do a lot (on desktop). Why not design a page at 100%?

Comment: To be honest, i had no idea i was designing it at 90%!!:( but thanks anyway